# When should we use static map?

Tags: java, performance, dictionary, object, static

I just have a small question about optimization.
What is the best between:

**- Using a static map in a class and interact with it with static methods.**

```
public class Manager {

    public static Map<String, Long> ids = new HashMap<>();

    public static Long getId(String name) {
        return ids.get(name);
    }

}

public class RandomClass {

    public void randomMethod(String name) {
        Manager.getId(name);
    }

}
```

**- Using only one instance of Manager Object that is saved in the only instance of MainClass and interact with the map with this unique instance of Manager Object.**

```
public class Manager {

    public Map<String, Long> ids = new HashMap<>();

    public Manager() {}

    public Long getId(String name) {
        return ids.get(name);
    }

}

public class MainClass {

    private static MainClass instance;
    private Manager manager;

    public void initialize() {
        manager = new Manager();
    }

    public static MainClass getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public Manager getManager() {
        return manager;
    }

}

public class RandomClass {

    public void randomMethod() {
        MainClass.getInstance().getManager().getId(name);
    }

}
```

Thank you in advance for your answer.

Comment: The second one is cleaner because you can properly inject dependencies and can therefore test the code without much effort.

Comment: Yes it's more "beautiful" but is it more expensive for Java ? I mean, is it more optimized or less than using static map ? Thank you for your quick reply.

Comment: That is irrelevant. And most certainly the difference is negligible.

Comment: The simply rule of thumb is: you don't make things static unless you have to. See is as *abnormality*. It is not your first design option, but your last.